# Send ngFor index as a parameter of a function

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ngfor

I need to send the index of a *ngFor as part of a parameter of a function:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of deviceGroups.groups | orderBy: 'description'; let i = index">
  <li class="group-item"><mat-checkbox>{{ group.name }} </mat-checkbox>
    <mat-icon (click)="collapseGroup('g{{ i }}')">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
  </li>
  <div id="g{{ i }}">
    Some content here that I want to hide when I click in the Mat-icon
  </div>
</div>
```

If you notice, the content that I want to hide is `id="g{{ i }}"` . It actually works, but there is a problem when I want to do the same but as a parameter of the function collapseGroup. When I write `(click)="collapseGroup('g{{ i }}')"` returns me an error.

Also, how do I set the display='none' of the  in my component.ts? I mean something like in JavaScript:

```
funtion collapseGroup(gid)
{
  document.getElementById(gid).style.display = 'none';
}
```

but in my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use annotations while passing a function parameter  , you can do that inside your function

```
 <mat-icon (click)="collapseGroup(i)">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
```

something like,

```
collapseGroup(gid)
{
  document.getElementById('g'+gid).style.display = 'none';
}
```